# ¿Cómo puedo verificar la access_token de GitHub?

Tags: api, github

Estoy creando una aplicacion con agular donde poder iniciar sección con GitHub y un backend de api rest.
No se que api de GitHub utilizar para verificar el access_token que me da github en el backend para verificar que el token es valido y no es falso o esta expirado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será que necesitas ir a la [documentación](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#check-an-authorization) y usar algo como esto (el ejemplo usa curl):

`curl -u client_id:client_secret https://api.github.com/applications/:client_id/tokens/:token`